# String cannot be converted to int. How to sum scanned ints in Java?

Tags: java, string, sum, integer

I wrote this simple program to sum ints input by the user, but when I compile it, it says that "String cannot be converted to int." What is wrong in this program?

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Pr6{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int sum;

        System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
        num1 = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
        num2 = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
        num3 = scan.nextLine();

        sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
        System.out.print("Total = " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do realize that you have to turn strings into ints before you can add their values, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your issue

```
num1 = scan.nextLine();
```

Let's look at what data type num1 is:

```
int num1;
```

`scan.nextLine()` will return a String. And you can't have int num1 = "1", because they are different data types.

You should use `scan.nextInt()`. It will return a number. That'll solve your problems :)

So you'll have `num1 = scan.nextInt()`, `num2 = scan.nextInt()`, and `num3 = scan.nextInt()`.

I hope that helps. Good luck!